# I'm trying to get that day - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a script that finds that day, date and year.
But two days it should say "I am closed" below the day...
those two days is 'Søndag' and 'Onsdag'
I have tried to make an if statement but it doesn't seem to work :(

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS - Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b id="calendar-day"></b> -
    <b id="calendar-date"></b>
    <b id="calendar-month-year"></b>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS

```
//function that gets the day and date
function calendar() {
    var day = ['Søndag', 'Mandag','Tirsdag','Onsdag','Torsdag','Fredag','Lørdag'];
    var month = ['Januar','Febuar','Marts','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','December'];
    var d = new Date();
    setText('calendar-day', day[d.getDay()]);
    setText('calendar-date', d.getDate());
    setText('calendar-month-year', month[d.getMonth()]+' '+(1900+d.getYear()));
    checkDay();
};

//function that sees if it's closing day
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

function checkDay() {
  if (day == 'Onsdag') {
    paragraph.innerText = 'I am closed';
  }
}

function setText(id, val){
    if(val < 10){
        val = '0' + val;    //add leading 0 if val < 10
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};

window.onload = calendar;
```

Comment: `day` does not equal "Onsdag". `day` is an array holding all weekdays.

Comment: Then how do I get the 'Onsdag'? :)

Comment: to avoid confusion, you should call "days" the array holding all days.

Comment: How did you get it the first time? `day[d.getDay()]`…

Comment: You do it already, just send day[d.getDay()] as an argument to your checkDay function and use that argument for validating the day

Comment: @deceze like this? if (day[d.getDay()] == 'Onsdag')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably You are trying to do this. You cant directly access `day` into checkDay function rather you need to pass it as a parameter and then. Secondly, You can't directly extract a value from day because it's an array not integer or string, so you need to loop through the array in order to find the right value

```js
function calendar() {
    var day = ['Søndag', 'Mandag','Tirsdag','Onsdag','Torsdag','Fredag','Lørdag'];
    var month = ['Januar','Febuar','Marts','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','December'];
    var d = new Date();
    var today = day[d.getDay()];
    setText('calendar-day', today);
    setText('calendar-date', d.getDate());
    setText('calendar-month-year', month[d.getMonth()]+' '+(1900+d.getYear()));
    checkDay(today);
};

//function that sees if it's closing day
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

function checkDay(day) {
  if (day == 'Onsdag' || day == 'Søndag') {
      paragraph.innerText = 'I am closed';
    } else paragraph.innerText = 'I am opened';
 
}

function setText(id, val){
    if(val < 10){
        val = '0' + val;    //add leading 0 if val < 10
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};

window.onload = calendar;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS - Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b id="calendar-day"></b> -
    <b id="calendar-date"></b>
    <b id="calendar-month-year"></b>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You might as well replace that condition with `if (true)`, since it'll always determine that today should be closed.

Comment: Yeah, but your code is not working. If you change if (d == 'Onsdag') { to if (d == 'Torsdag') { it still says "I am closed" but today is not Thursday its wednesday

Comment: ohhh. Okay. I didn't get your question. Let me fix it

Comment: if the day is Onsdagn or Søndag this will print "closed"

Answer (score 2):

The most prized quality in a developer is *laziness*. Don't be messing around in the reeds there :-) Use the Date object to manipulate dates, and, these days, there's really no excuse for not using Vue when you want to manipulate the DOM.

To get danish weekdays, use `myDate.toLocaleDateString('da-DK',{weekday:'long'})`. The same goes for month names. Docs are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

To find out if a day is on the weekend, use `(myDate.getDay() === 6) || (myDate.getDay() === 0);`

Here's your example working, with 13 lines of script and 6 lines of markup.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el : "#vueRoot",
  data : { myDate : new Date() },
  computed : {
    formattedDate(){
     return this.myDate.toLocaleDateString(
      'da-DK',
      {weekday:'long', day:'numeric', month:'long', year:'numeric'}
     );
    },
    isOpen(){return !(this.myDate.getDay() === 3 || this.myDate.getDay() === 0)}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vueRoot">
  <b>{{formattedDate}}</b>
  <br>
  {{isOpen?'I am OPEN':'I am CLOSED'}}
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have passed day into checkDay:

```js
//function that gets the day and date

function calendar() {
    var day = ['Søndag', 'Mandag','Tirsdag','Onsdag','Torsdag','Fredag','Lørdag'];
    var month = ['Januar','Febuar','Marts','April','Maj','Juni','Juli','August','September','Oktober','November','December'];
    var d = new Date();
    setText('calendar-day', day[d.getDay()]);
    desiredDay = day[d.getDay()];
    setText('calendar-date', d.getDate());
    setText('calendar-month-year', month[d.getMonth()]+' '+(1900+d.getYear()));
    checkDay(desiredDay);
};

//function that sees if it's closing day
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

function checkDay(day) {
  if (day == 'Onsdag') {
    paragraph.innerText = 'I am closed';
  }
}

function setText(id, val){
    if(val < 10){
        val = '0' + val;    //add leading 0 if val < 10
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val;
};

window.onload = calendar;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS - Testing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b id="calendar-day"></b> -
    <b id="calendar-date"></b>
    <b id="calendar-month-year"></b>
    <p></p>
  </body>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

day was undefined in the checkDay function